quantum espresso assume isolate 2D confusion
I have been playing with a PTO ferroelectric slab in vacuum with Quantum Espresso. More specifically, I wanted to understand what the assume_isolated = '2D' does. My understanding was that it is another way to perform a dipole correction when doing slab calculations.
So here is the case: my slab is 5 PTO unit-cells thick along the z axis with 20 Angstrom of vacuum on either side. So it is well above the required limit for the '2D' flag. The slab is periodic in x and y axis and has a polarization that is oriented towards the negative side of the z axis.
When I plot the Hartree potential with option 11 in pp.x and I average along the z axis, I get the following:

The blue curve corresponds to the above mentioned polarized case and the orange curve is for the centro-symetric case when there is no ferroelectric polarization. The red dashed lines represent the geometrical limits of the slab.
Here are my questions:

what are those different regions in vacuum? in the centro-symetric case there are two regions where the hartree potential is flat. What are those?

in the ferroelectric case, there are again two different regions in vacuum, but this time in one there appears to be an electric field. what is that?


The documentation for this is very very scarce. Apart from the original paper on the method I can't find much more information about how to actually use this method with quantum espresso. What am I doing wrong?
